# Write Kinect joint positions to txt on button click

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I would like to write joint positions to a txt file.
I have a method to get the X,Y,Z positions of one joint.

```
  public void positions(Skeleton skeleton)
    {
        // get the joint
        Joint rightHand = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight];

        // get the individual points of the right hand
        double rightX = rightHand.Position.X;
        double rightY = rightHand.Position.Y;
        double rightZ = rightHand.Position.Z;     
    }
```

and I have my click method

```
  private void stoji_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

           File.AppendAllText(@"E:\skuska.txt", rightX + ", " + rightY + ", " +rightZ + Environment.NewLine);

    }
```

But obviously the rightX, rightY and rightZ cannot be seen from onclick method. And if I add the code from positions method to onclick method, it does not recognize "skeleton".

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `rightX`, `rightY`, `rightZ` instance variables of your class.

```
public class MyKinect
{
   private double rightX;
   private double rightY;
   private double rightZ;

   public void positions(Skeleton skeleton)
   {
      // get the joint
      Joint rightHand = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight];

      // get the individual points of the right hand
      rightX = rightHand.Position.X;
      rightY = rightHand.Position.Y;
      rightZ = rightHand.Position.Z;     
   }

   private void stoji_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      File.AppendAllText(@"E:\skuska.txt", rightX + ", " + rightY + ", " +rightZ + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```